# jQuery validation: a field that must to be 0 or multiple of 20

Tags: jquery, validation

i'm trying to validate (jQuery validation plugin) a field musts to be 0 or multiple of 20 (0, 20, 40, 60, ...).
Anybody knows how to make it?

Comment: `var test = this.value%20 === 0;`

Comment: 0%20 is 0 : http://jsfiddle.net/PcaU4/

Answer (score 3):

Add a custom validation method

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("special", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value, 10) % 20 == 0
}, 'The value must be 0 or a multiple of 20');
```

then

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            special: true
        }
    },
    messages: {}
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tCqG8/)

Answer (score 2):

Use Modulus:

```
var num = //your field num
if(num%20 == 0){
    //code here
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rc2yj/2/)

Comment: don't forget to `$.trim` and `parseInt` the field first...  Field values are strings, not numbers.

Comment: @A.Wolff _probably_, but it's always best to ensure that your variables are explicitly converted to the expected type (with error trapping as needed) rather than rely on implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation allows you to set any multiple to validate:

```
$.validator.addMethod("multiples", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value, 10) % param == 0
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a multiple of {0}"));
```

Then use either of these formats to invoke the validation (multiples of 12 allowed in the examples):

```
    <input type="text" name="qty" class="required" multiples="12">
```

or

```
$("#myform").validate( {
 rules: {
        qty : {
            required: true,
            multiples: 12
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.validator.addMethod("multiples", function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || parseInt(value, 10) % param == 0
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a multiple of {0}"));
```

Comment: Code only answers are allowed, but it's encouraged to explain the answer as well. Consider adding some explanation.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.